# Dash was not successfully imported. Make sure you don't have a file named 'dash.py' in your current directory

Tags: dashboard, plotly-dash

This error showed up randomly after I had been running plotly-dash scripts for weeks.

"Dash was not successfully imported. Make sure you don't have a file named 'dash.py' in your current directory"

1. I've uninstalled and reinstalled dash (didn't work)
2. I found a file named dash.py in a Dash file but when I change the name or remove it, it causes other errors to show (didn't work )
3. "It sounds like something is wrong with the installation of the Dash package. What does the contents of that **init**.py look like? It should be this:

[https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/master/dash/**init**.py](https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/master/dash/__init__.py)" I did this too and (didn't work)

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities to solve this:

- Check if there is a file 'test.py' in your scripts' folder. Change its name to something else.
- Down version of Dash to 1.12.0 or below
  (credit: https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/1143)

Comment: renaming a local file in my root source directory from `test.py` (to `tests.py`) worked for me